# How to play html 5 video on top of svg element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, html5-video

I have a hexagon shape **svg** element with an image as pattern inside (worker picture).

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1400" height="1550" viewBox="0 0 140 155" class="svgMember memberPicLeft" id="erikSvg">
  <defs>
     <pattern id="svgImg" x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1">
       <image x="-10" y="-40" width="120%" height="160% xlink:href="assets/img/picture.jpg"></image>
     </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#svgImg)" 
    d="M69.999,153.831c-1.797,0-3.596-0.466-5.208-1.396L7.708,119.479c-3.222-1.861-5.208-5.3-5.208-9.021V44.542
    c0-3.721,1.986-7.159,5.208-9.021L64.791,2.564c1.612-0.93,3.411-1.396,5.208-1.396c1.799,0,3.598,0.466,5.209,1.396l57.083,32.957
    c3.224,1.861,5.21,5.3,5.21,9.021v65.916c0,3.721-1.986,7.159-5.21,9.021l-57.083,32.957
    C73.596,153.365,71.797,153.831,69.999,153.831z"/>
</svg>
```

How can I add a video to the svg element, so that on hover the video will play masked with the element (-webkit-mask-image): *contained by the element borders*.
I tried to just add video tag:

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay>
   <source id="mp4_src" src="assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This of course is not working. Didn't find any solutions on google. 
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

SVG does not support the video element. I have seen some experimental builds of Opera and Firefox that have had supported it, but common browsers do not.

You could attach a video as an overlay by using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Pretty sure no Firefox build has ever supported video. I tried integrating it at one time but it turned into a rats nest of code changes.

Comment: That's an html video element, not an SVG video element. Firefox has supported that for years and continues to do so, no experimental build is required.

Comment: Fixed it by puttin video inside div and using clip-path to get the desired shape. Thanks for the help!